# How will you know if k is constant for O(n^k) in subset sum?

Tags: algorithm, input, np, polynomials, subset-sum

Subset sum problem: Given a set of numbers `S` and a target number let say `0`. The aim is to find a subset `S’` of `S` such that the elements in it add up to `0`. I heard that this problem becomes polynomial if the size of `S’` is given.
For example, if you have a clue that `3` elements add up to `0` we can come up with complexity `O(n^3)`.

The class P consists of those problems that are solvable in polynomial time. For example, they could be solved in `O(n^k)` for some constant `k`, where `n` is the size of the input.
`(n^k)` denotes the number of subsets of size `k` of `[n]`; or, equivalently, the number of ways in which we can select `k` diferent elements from an `n`-element set.
With `n` elements; a `k`-subset of a set is a subset with `k` elements.

Therefore let say there is an algorithm in polynomial time that finds or locate the `k`-subset that sum to `0` from `n` elements. I mean if `k` is an input of the algorithm such that `k` can also be greater than `3`. Can we say `k` is constant or what?

Comment: not sure I understand fully, but yeah in what you explain, k is an unknown constant

Comment: Everything depends on whether you consider |S'| to be part of the *input* to the problem -- that is, if it is allowed to vary across problem instances.  If it is not allowed to vary then in effect *you have a distinct problem per value of |S'|, each of which is solvable in polynomial time*.  This is a valid, not often not a *useful* statement to make.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean for k to be constant in O(n^k)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748910/what-does-it-mean-for-k-to-be-constant-in-onk)

Answer (score 1):

If the running time of an algorithm for some problem with some input is bounded by `O(n^k)`, it depends on various things whether this runtime bound is considered to be polynomial, pseudo-polynomial or none of these. If `k` is some *specific* constant like `k=3`, the bound is polynomial. If `k` is part of the input, the runtime bound is *not* considered polynomially bounded.

The concept of runtime bounds is briefly explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity); however note that informal usage of the term 'polynomial runtime bound' is usually somewhat sloppy. In the most exact sense, an algorithm *A* solving a problem *P* can have a runtime bound that is *polynomially bounded in the encoding length of its input*. This means that the the bound also is to be seen in relation to the specific encoding of instances of *P* for *A*.

Furthermore, as usually a binary encoding of numbers is used for algorithms, the encoded numbers may grow exponentially in their encoding length. If *A* has a runtime bound that is polynomially bounded in a numeric value of its input, but not bounded in the encoding length of the input, the bound is said to be *pseudo-polynomial*, as briefly explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time).

I hope this helps, the specific details are usually a bit inaccurate in informal explanations.